# AngularJS have ng-view display a dynamic footer outside of its div

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm fairly new to angular.js so I'm seeking advice on how to best implement the functionality described here. I have an html body with header, sidebar and a content area provided by `<div class="container-fluid" ng-view></div>`. Because this is a standard twitter-bootstrap layout , the `ng-view` is not a direct descendant of the `body` element.

I have one view that shall contain an infinitely scrollable list. When at least one element of the list is selected, I want to slide-up a footer that contains contextual actions (the footer shall be `position:fixed` so that it's always displayed on top of the list). In essence this is similar to what happens on the Windows 8 Metro home-screen when you right click a tile.

The problem I now have is that the footer can't be part of the `ng-view` partial because it needs to live directly under the `body` in the DOM. What's a good way to handle this with Angular.js and `ng-view` when I'd want to keep a single controller for the list and the dynamic footer? If there's a CSS solution to this, I'd be happy to hear about it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to have the footer outside the `ng-view` element in order to handle the layout you are wanting. I'll leave the layout/CSS to you but the following example demonstrates a way to communicate with the directive if it were to live outside ng-view.

Here's a plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/NpoIrOdfvn9XZiXY9YyV?p=preview).

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="someApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
    <footer-directive></footer-directive>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('someApp', []).config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        template: '<p>template</p>',
        controller: 'SomeCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}).service('broadcastService', function($rootScope, $log) {
    this.broadcast = function(eventName, payload) {
        $log.info('broadcasting: ' + eventName + payload);
        $rootScope.$broadcast(eventName, payload);
    };
}).controller('SomeCtrl', function(broadcastService, $log, $timeout) {
    //fire off showfooter message
    broadcastService.broadcast('ShowFooter', {
        some: 'data'
    });

    // wait 3 seconds and hide footer
    $timeout(function() {
        //fire off hide message
        broadcastService.broadcast('HideFooter');
    }, 3000);

}).directive('footerDirective', function(broadcastService, $log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
            elm.hide();
            scope.$on('ShowFooter', function(payload) {
                $log.info('payload received');
                $log.debug(payload);
                // assuming you have jQuery
                elm.show();
            });
            scope.$on('HideFooter', function() {
                // assuming you have jQuery
                elm.hide();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How does that solve the problem that different ng-views whant to swap out the template displayed in the Footer (+ controll it)?

Comment: Having the directives/controllers outside of ng-view keep them from swapping out.

Comment: But that's exactly what I want to accomplish. The content of the footer should change with the ng-view

Comment: so... you want a view to load with the list and a footer? So this is more of a layout issue? Forgive my ignorance, I am just trying to paint a picture. Do you have a fiddle or plunker to share?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Due to layout constraints however, the footer must live outside the ng-view. It's probably just me being stupid. I am right now experimenting with decorating $dialog to do my bidding and dynamically inject the footer.

Comment: You could have the footer remain dormant outside the ng-view and react to messages broadcasted from elsewhere in the app.

Comment: I'll leave the layout/CSS to you but my updated answer demonstrates a way to communicate with the directive if it were to live outside ng-view.